# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
try
{
    types = Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    continue;  // Can't load as .NET assembly, so ignore
}
```

Can any one have solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting **FileNotFoundException**
assemblyFile is not found, or the module you are trying to load does not specify a filename extension.

Kindly, please make sure your assembly file full path is accurate. Further, In short, Assembly.LoadFrom allows assembly to be loaded once from a path from which it has not been loaded yet.

Try this **Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath));**

Comment: I tried all this, but in vain.